# Get Video URL from a Link

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I try to get Video link from a link, In browser Inspect element video link showing. but when i see Page Source is Empty. I try dom parser and other it not show any

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain');

include 'HTML5/Parser.php';

$html = "http://www.nowvideo.co/mobile/#/videos/029361d6b060a";
$d = HTML5_Parser::parse($html);

echo $d->saveHTML();
?>
```

How can i get Mp4 link from this url?

```
 http://www.nowvideo.co/mobile/#/videos/029361d6b060a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you have posted is making an ajax request to

http://www.nowvideo.co/mobile/ajax.php?videoId=029361d6b060a

which returns a JSON object:

```
{
    "total_count" : 1,
    "items" : [{
            "id" : "029361d6b060a",
            "title" : "Infini.2015.HDRip.XviD.AC3-EVO",
            "desc" : "",
            "pic" : "play.png",
            "fullurl" : "video.php?id=029361d6b060a",
            "download" : "video.php?id=029361d6b060a&download=1&key=c17e9dc935424de478ccff158806178f",
            "videoLink" : "http:\/\/www.nowvideo.co\/video\/"
         }
    ]
}
```

Then I presume as the other video web sites do it, there is some javascript logic that processes this JSON object and constructs links to videos so that it would not be easy to copy such videos.

Your best option would be to try to reverse engineer such javascript logic, but I think this can be illegal.